# bind image uri to flatlist react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to bind image uri to flatlist. But it's not. rendering ..

```
this.state = {
        data: [

            {
                avatar: 'require(../../resources/icons/MyAccount/rounduser.png)', text: 'Bank Accounts', val: ''
            },
            {
                avatar: 'require(../../resources/icons/MyAccount/rounduser.png)', text: 'PrePaid-Cards', val: ''
            },
            {
                avatar: 'require(../../resources/icons/MyAccount/rounduser.png)', text: 'Other Wallets', val: ''
            },
            {
                avatar: 'require(../../resources/icons/MyAccount/rounduser.png)', text: 'Help', val: ''
            },
            {
                avatar: 'require(../../resources/icons/MyAccount/rounduser.png)', text: 'About App', val: ''
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I'm using this method. to render  RenderItem for flatlist

```
_renderList = ({ item }) => {
    return (
        <View style={styles.listContainer}  >
            <Image style={styles.listImage}  source={item.avatar}  />
            <Text style={styles.listText} >{item.text}</Text>
            <Text style={styles.listVal} >{item.val}</Text>
            <Image style={styles.listImage} source={require('../../resources/icons/MyAccount/arrowright.png')} />
        </View>
    );

}
```

It's rendering  empty space. Is there something I'm missing ?

Comment: Check your styles.

Comment: it has nothing to do with styles.. passing base64 string renders perfectly. only issue with URI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `require` inside string. It should be plain require:

`avatar: require('../../resources/icons/MyAccount/rounduser.png')`

Comment: it. should be   avatar:require('../../resporces...').. Please edit. your answer. so that I can. accept it.

Comment: @KartiikeyaBaleneni true. Made a fix too quickly and didn't notice that. I fixed it.